# Sanitizing Form Input in PDO-based Query

Tags: php, forms, web, pdo

I have been batting my head against the wall trying to solve a problem associated with what seems to be deprecated code.

Working with an example from Vikram Vaswani's "PHP: A Beginner's Guide," the goal is to validate and properly escape input from a user's web form for entry into an SQLite table. I have consulted many sources that all point me toward using a syntax such as:

`$todo->prepare($_POST['name'])` within a conditional block that assigns the result to a variable for use in the final query for insertion to the database table. The best result I have been able to get, no matter what I have done is a NULL. The worst is a failure to execute the query.

I have read the manual and apologize if this is a duplicate question, but there may be a Microsoft Windows-specific issue related to PDO libraries of which I am unaware. I have been getting nowhere fast.

The form fields are as follows:

Three fields associated with date: 'dd', 'mm' and 'yyyy'.

The code that seems to fail every time follows:

```
 try {

// If form submitted
// attempt database connection.

$toDo = new PDO('sqlite:todo.db') OR
exit("Could not open database.");

// Check and sanitize input.

$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $name = $toDo->prepare($_POST['name']) :
exit('ERROR: Task name is required.');

$dd = !empty($_POST['dd']) ? $dd = (int) $_POST['dd'] :
exit('ERROR: Task due date is required.');

    $mm = !empty($_POST['mm']) ? $mm = (int) $_POST['mm'] :
exit('ERROR: Task due date is required.');

$yyyy = !empty($_POST['yyyy']) ? $yyyy = (int) $_POST['yyyy'] :
exit('ERROR: Task due date is required.');

// Create entry date variable.

$date = checkdate($mm, $dd, $yyyy) ? mktime(0, 0, 0, $mm, $dd, $yyyy) :
exit('ERROR: Task due date is invalid.');

$priority = !empty($_POST['priority']) ?
$priority = $toDo->prepare($_POST['priority']) :
exit('ERROR: Task priority is required.');

// Attempt query execution.
// Add a new record.

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (name, due, priority) VALUES
('$name', '$date', '$priority')";

if ($toDo->prepare(exec($sql) == TRUE)) {

     echo "<div id=\"message\">Task record successfully added to database</div>";

}   else {

     echo "ERROR: Could not execute query.";

}

// Close connection to sqlite3.

$toDo = NULL;

 }

 catch(PDOException $e) {

 echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();

}   // end catch
```

I have been unable to find any errors in the above code. Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is this line:

`if ($toDo->prepare(exec($sql) == TRUE)) {`

`exec()` is a PHP function for running command line programs. I think what you actually wanted was to call the `PDOStatement::execute` method.

See the manual for proper usage of `PDO::prepare`:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Thank you for this information. Unfortunately I still seem to be facing errors. This time another one. My revised code is:

Comment: Thank you for this information. Unfortunately I still seem to be facing errors. This time another one. My revised code is as follows:                                                                     if ($toDo->execute($sql) == TRUE)                                      This produces the following errors:                       bool(false) 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in I:\Web\Apache2\htdocs\web_programming_pages\php_beginner\chapter_7\projects\save.php on line 102

Comment: You need to call execute() on the instance of PDOStatement you get back from PDO::prepare rather than on your original instance of PDO. Start a new file and build the example from the manual step by step to learn how it works and forget the book you were reading as far as this is concerned, since it's obviously confusing you.

Comment: To clarify: you need to do something like this: $statement = $toDo->prepare($sql); $statement->execute();

Comment: Thank you for your additional assistance. I have tried valiantly, including looking at the PHP manual, and still run into a problem. My revised code is:                                         $pdoStatement = $toDo->prepare($sql); 
if ($pdoStatement->execute() == TRUE) {...                         Now when I have a "dangerous" string, I get the following message:   string(20) "See Finian's Rainbow" 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in I:\Web\Apache2\htdocs\web_programming_pages\php_beginner\chapter_7\projects\save.php on line 103.

Comment: One of the big points of using PDO is that you can use prepared statements, which prevent a major security vulnerability called SQL injection. So instead of $name, $date, $priority as in your example you'd use ?, ?, ? and then pass array($name, $date, $priority) as the second parameter to prepare(). If it still doesn't work then please post the full code of your attempt.